# Obtain Key SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables in which the second table has a foreign key which is defined as table 1's primary key. Under the add operation how can I reference the newly added table 1 key to use as table 2's foreign key?

```
// Project Table columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id"; // Primary, integer
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name"; // Unique, text

// Images Table column names
private static final String KEY_IM_ID = "id"; // Primary, integer
private static final String IM_URI = "uri"; // text
private static final String PROJ_IMAGE_ID = "proImgId"; // foreign for Projects Table

public void addProject(Project project) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values_PT = new ContentValues(); // PROJECTS TABLE
    ContentValues values_IT = new ContentValues(); // IMAGES TABLE

    values_PT.put(KEY_NAME, project.getName()); // project name
    // does the KEY ID get added on its own?

    values_IT.put(IM_URI, project.getURI()); // image uri
            values_IT.put(PROJ_IMAGE_ID, ????????); 
    }
```

PROJ_IMAGE_ID needs to have KEY_ID's value, however I do not know how retrieve it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ID columns are declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then they are [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and will get their value automatically if you don't set them when inserting.

To get the ID of a new record, you have to actually insert the record first; the new ID is the return value of the [`insert()` function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29).

Comment: ahh okay so I would just store it in some long value? For example: 

   `Long keyId = db.insert(PROJECT_TABLE, null, values_PT);`

Comment: Yes (or an `int` if you have less than four billion records).